# Can I have one Maven assembly descriptor depend on another?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Here is a snippet from my pom file.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/config/a.xml</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>src/main/config/b.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I would like descriptor b.xml to depend on what a.xml generates (a jar with included dependencies).
Is this possible? How would I specify this in my b.xml descriptor?

Answer (score 1):

Use two executions, one for a.xml and then one for b.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly-a</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/config/a.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly-b</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attached</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/config/b.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```